# Handle RTP packets

Tags: javascript, rtsp, rtp

I am trying to display the feed from my NVR on a local webpage.

The NVR has a built in webpage that it does this from but it is lacking some features that i'd like to have.

I have successfully used javascript to open the websocket that the nvr serves and autheticate via it's digest auth.

The websocket now streams packets but i am a little stuck as to what to do with the packets. Ultimately i'd like to display the feed in a canvas. I believe the packets are rtp h264.

I can create a pastebin of some of the packet HEX if that would be helpful.

If you need to see anything else, let me know.

Comment: Seeing the packet dump would help

Comment: In what format? HEX?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/6zfKQZJ4